# 0 Action from Facebook Mobile Ad for Android app

Tags: android, facebook

Our Facebook mobile ad for a native Android app got 300 (3% CTR) clicks today, but 0 Action.

A similar ad for our iOS version would generate 30 Actions.

We have entered all the Facebook settings for Native Android app.

what could be wrong?

Google Play link http://goo.gl/5Zjkm

regards,
Michael